# Make AWS Lambda call itself again after completing a task

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an AWS Lambda function which does a couple of API calls then saves whatever information it gets to a DynamoDB table.

Would it be a good practice for me send a message to an SQS queue after completing whatever the Lambda was doing? The queue will then trigger the Lambda function to start another process again.

So with regards to processing and the costs involved, is this a good idea or not?

The other idea I had was to trigger the Lambda function using a CloudWatch Event but the problem is I want it to start the new process once the old one has completed so if it happens that the Lambda function gets triggered while processing its then going to stuff up my records on DynamoDB.

So if anyone has a better solution or alternative let me know.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to accomplish? For example, _why_ do you wish to call the Lambda function again? Are you trying to process multiple items from a queue of work? Feel free to edit your question to provide more information about your actual workflow so that we can provide an appropriate answer.

Comment: i do an API call which i then take the results and upload them to S3, if the upload is successful i store a count in a DynamoDB which is then used in the next call. So once the count is saved on the table the lambda Stops so i want to execute it again immediately after finishing the process to start again and do the process

Comment: But _why_ do you wish to do this? Why do you need to keep triggering Lambda? Why can't you just call Lambda once? Are you scraping from a website? We really can't give you any suggestions unless we understand why you are doing this rather strange process.

Comment: Step functions?